# Find the maximum value for each group in dataframe and retrieve the entire row

Tags: r, dataframe

I've the following dataframe (With many records) and would like to retrieve the entire row for each day with maximum differences.

[image: Table]

```
require(dplyr)
# This gets the maximum value for each date
maxInfo = results %>% group_by(t) %>% summarise(Value = max(differences))
```

I'm able to get the max value for each day but how to get the entire row?

Comment: `filter(Difference == max(Difference))` instead of `summarise`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, using `slice_max`:

```
library(dplyr)

results %>% group_by(t) %>% slice_max(differences)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. Will accept the answer after 10 minutes (Stackoverflow restriction).

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` method if speed is important

```
results[ results[, .I[ differences == max(differences )], .(t)]$V1 ]
```